# Python function not returning anything

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def equip(x):
    global bag_sword
    global bag_chest
    global bag_gloves
    global bag_helmet
    while x == "iron sword" and "iron sword" in bag:
        if bag_sword:
            print "You can't have 2 weapons equipped!"
            x = ""
        print "\nYou equip the iron sword.\n"
        bag.remove("iron sword")
        bag_sword.append("iron sword")
```

When I run this the first time, it works fine, but when I run it a second time nothing happens.

`bag_sword` is a list

test code:

```
bag.append("iron sword")
if input1[:5] == "equip":
    print input1[:5]
    equip(input1[6:])
    print input1[6:]
I type into the console 'equip iron sword'
```

I've tried using a variable in place of the `input[]`

(It isn't syntax)

Comment: You function reads and mutates global variables, so it won't necessarily do the same thing each time it is called. What do you want to happen?

Comment: What this is supposed to do is add a weapon to bag_sword if nothing is there, and tell the player they' can't have 2 equipped if one is already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can make the function work as described:

```
bag_sword = []

def equip(x):
    global bag_sword
    if x == "iron sword":
        if "iron sword" in bag_sword:
            print "You can't have 2 weapons equipped!"
        else:
            bag_sword.append("iron sword")

print bag_sword # Prints "[]".
equip("iron sword") # Prints nothing. Puts the string "iron sword" in bag_sword.
print bag_sword # Prints "['iron sword']".
equip("iron sword") # Prints "You can't have 2 weapons equipped!". bag_sword is unchanged.
```

Comment: I ended up fixing this with a few tweaks to yours. I don't know why I used a while loop, I've been at this for a few days now heh, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make nwk's solution more general (also try to get rid of global variables):

```
def equip(item, bag):
    if item in bag:
        print "You can't have 2 {}s equipped!".format(item)
    else:
        bag.append(item)

def main():
    bag_sword = []
    print bag_sword
    equip("iron sword", bag_sword) 
    print bag_sword
    equip("iron sword", bag_sword)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It also seems to me that a dictionary or class would be a better alternative than several bag lists:

```
def equip(item, slot, inventory):
    if inventory[slot] == item:
        print 'Already equipped.'
    else:
        inventory[slot] = item
        print item.capitalize(), 'equipped.'

def main():
    inventory = {
        'weapon': None,
        'gloves': None,
        }

    equip('iron sword', 'weapon', inventory)
    print inventory
    equip('iron sword', 'weapon', inventory)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```